# jquery - fade only one thumb at a time

Tags: jquery

I want only is fade the thumbnail one at a time in my existing code when hover one thumb all thumb hover also, is there any way to make it. when hover, only that thumb have hover effect?

demo is [here!](http://jsfiddle.net/ApA8J/1/)

**js**

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{    
    $(".hoverMe").hover(
      function () {
        $("div.fadeHover").fadeIn('slow');
      }, 
      function () {
        $("div.fadeHover").fadeOut('slow');
      }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to target current hover `.hoverMe` as well as **[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** to target only sibling `.fadeHover` of hovered image:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hoverMe").hover(function () { 
        $(this).siblings('.fadeHover').stop().fadeIn('slow');
    }, function () { 
        $(this).siblings('.fadeHover').stop().fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

You can also use **[.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)** to stop current animation so your animation will behave properly as what you expect.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ApA8J/6/)**

---

Seem like you need to target `.wrap` div instead of `.hoverMe` image here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".wrap").hover(function () { 
        $(this).find('.fadeHover').stop().fadeIn();
    }, function () { 
        $(this).find('.fadeHover').stop().fadeOut();
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ApA8J/7/)**

Comment: can we adjust the delay when you hover the thumb it appears late?

Answer (score 2):

You need to target relative element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hoverMe").hover(function () {
        $(this).closest('li').find(".fadeHover").fadeIn('slow');
    }, function () {
        $(this).closest('li').find("div.fadeHover").fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/ApA8J/3/)**</kbd>

In this case the you need to target the `fadeHover` element which is in the same `li` as the hovered `hoverMe` element

Comment: thanks for your answer is there any way to make fade in/out appear only once?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
    $(".hoverMe").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().find("div.fadeHover").fadeIn('slow');
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().find("div.fadeHover").fadeOut('slow');
      }
    );
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ApA8J/4/)